# TypeError: clientes.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, json, react, api

Preciso listar alguns registros, porém está me retornando um erro:

```
TypeError: clientes.map is not a function
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import api from '../src/services/api';


class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      clientes: [],
    }

  }
 

  async componentDidMount() {
    const response = await api.get('');

    this.setState({clientes:response.data});
    
  }

  render() {

    const { clientes } = this.state;
    console.log(clientes)

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Listar os clientes</h1>
        {clientes.map(cliente => (
          <li key={cliente.show.id}>
            <h2>
              <strong>Título: </strong>
              {cliente.recordsets.nrCadstro}
            </h2>

          </li>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  };
};

export default App;
```

aqui esta minha api

```
import axios from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({
baseURL: 'http://localhost:3333/clientes'
});
export default api;
```